# Parameter replacement in method definitions to generate buttons with lots of properties

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm writing a GUI using PyQt5 in Python and have lots of PushButtons and Labels. As an example is below a definition of one button:

```
self.btnActive0 = QPushButton()
self.btnActive0.setText("Inactive")
self.btnActive0.setObjectName("btnActive0")
self.btnActive0.setFixedSize(ACTIVE_WIDTH, ACTIVE_HEIGHT)
self.btnActive0.setCheckable(True)
self.btnActive0.setStyleSheet(
    'font-family: Arial; '
    'font-size: 12pt; '
    'color: blue; '
    'background-color:lightcyan; '
    'font-weight: bold;'
    )
self.btnActive0.clicked.connect(self.setActive0)
self.bottomLayout.addWidget(self.btnActive0)
```

And I'm trying to write a method for generating the buttons and to give the parameters in only one line for each button btnActive0, btnActive1, . . . btnActiveN as below:

```
def createButtons(self, hdl, txt, wid, hei, stat, fnt, siz, fg, bg, wei, com):
    self.hdl = QPushButton()
    self.hdl.setText(txt)
    self.hdl.setObjectName(hdl)
    self.hdl.setFixedSize(wid, hei)
    self.hdl.setCheckable(stat)
    self.hdl.setStyleSheet(
        "font-family: '{fnt}'; "
        "font-size: '{siz}'pt; "
        "color: '{fg}'; "
        "background-color:'{bg}'; "
        "font-weight: '{wei}';"
        )
    self.hdl.clicked.connect(self.com)
    self.bottomLayout.addWidget(self. hdl)

# Create the button __btnActive0__
createButtons(self, 'btnActive0', 'Inactive', ACTIVE_WIDTH, ACTIVE_HEIGHT, True, 'Arial', 12, 'blue', 'lightcyan', 'bold', 'setActive0')
```

It seems to be that the parameter replacements don't work as I've written like above.
It complains about the **com** parameter that the Mainindow doesn't have a **com** attribute. And the **hdl** argument is recognized only in **setObectName** method and not in **self.hdl**.
Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

@musicamante, no I didn't take any code from pyuic.
I've generated the whole GUI programmatically.
My GUI looks like the attached screenshot.

I've generated a minimal reproducible code with only two buttons.
I hope with that and the attached screenshot you can see my GUI structure
and explain to me[image] how to use the arguments in the method I've written above.
Regards
Mohsen

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget, QHBoxLayout)
import sys

WIDTH = 106
HEIGHT = 32

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedHeight(240)
        self.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.move(100, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle("Relais Lastdauertester") 

        self.createMainWindow()

    def createMainWindow(self):
        # Create Middle Layout
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.btnActive1 = QPushButton()
        self.btnActive1.setText("Inactive")
        self.btnActive1.setObjectName("btnActive1")
        self.btnActive1.setFixedSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        self.btnActive1.setCheckable(True)
        self.btnActive1.setStyleSheet(
            'font-family: Arial; '
            'font-size: 12pt; '
            'color: blue;'
            'background-color:lightcyan; '
            'font-weight: bold;'
            )
        self.btnActive1.clicked.connect(self.setActive1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btnActive1)

        self.btnActive2 = QPushButton()
        self.btnActive2.setText("Inactive")
        self.btnActive2.setObjectName("btnActive2")
        self.btnActive2.setFixedSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        self.btnActive2.setCheckable(True)
        self.btnActive2.setStyleSheet(
            'font-family: Arial; '
            'font-size: 12pt; '
            'color: blue;'
            'background-color:lightcyan; '
            'font-weight: bold;'
            )
        self.btnActive2.clicked.connect(self.setActive2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btnActive2)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def setActive1(self, pressed):
        source = self.sender()

        if pressed:
            source.setText("Active")
            self.btnActive1.setStyleSheet('font-family: Arial; '
                                          'font-size: 12pt; '
                                          'font-weight: bold; '
                                          'color: blue; '
                                          'background-color:lightgreen;')
        else:
            source.setText("Inactive")
            self.btnActive1.setStyleSheet('font-family: Arial; '
                                          'font-size: 12pt; '
                                          'font-weight: bold; '
                                          'color: blue; '
                                          'background-color:lightcyan;')

    def setActive2(self, pressed):
        pass

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Let me guess, you've got a file generated with pyuic and you're trying to modify it to your needs (or mimic what it does in your implementation)? In any case, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've added the minimal code above with a screenshot to see my GUI structure.
And to see why I need this createButtons method.